# cutil.h CUT_SAFE_CALL in CUDA 4.0

Tags: cuda

I am using CUDA 4.0 . I am trying to use the following functions.

```
CUT_DEVICE_INIT();
CUT_SAFE_CALL(cutCreateTimer(&hTimer));
```

I included cutil.h to use the above functions. But the compiler reports the following..

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cutil.h': No such file or directory
```

I searched in the CUDA directory but there is no file 'cutil.h'.
How can I find the time needed for a CUDA function using the above method? (not using the C++ timer)

Comment: I have the same problem with user570593. In cuda/4.0/cuda/include directory no such 'cutil.h' is present. This might be due to the difference between the one we have and SDK. Is there an equivalent header file to 'cutil.h' which might be found in include folder.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't tell your compiler where to find the file. I can't tell you exactly because you didn't provide details on what system you are using but for example, on Windows XP and assuming a default installation of version 4.0 of the SDK the cutil.h header file is in:

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\common\inc

For Windows 7 I think it is:

> C:\Program Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\common\inc

**but not sure.**